# Socialite not displaying icons

Tags: scripts

I was looking into using Socialite.js to load my twitter/facebook icons. I found [the following tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-lazy-loading-social-sharing-buttons-to-your-wordpress-blog/), which helped me to build the desired functionality.

The links display, but just as text (with HTML-list bullet points). Everything seems to be in place (css/js/sprite).

I know its a long shot, but anybody got any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the code I've used...hopefully it will make sense to somebody haha :)

**Function.php:**

```
function wptuts_load_socialiate() {
    // Register Socialite
    wp_register_script( 'socialite', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/socialite.min.js', array(), '', true );
    // Register social initialiser script
    wp_register_script( 'wptuts-social', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wptuts-social.js', array('jquery', 'socialite'), '', true );

    // Now enqueue Socialite
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wptuts-social' );

    // Register social CSS
    wp_register_style( 'wptuts-social', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/wptuts-social.css');

    // Now enqueue social
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wptuts-social' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_load_socialite' );

function social_after_the_content( $content ) {
    $custom_content .= $content;
    $custom_content .= '
<ul class="social-buttons cf">
    <li><a class="socialite twitter-share" href="http://twitter.com/share" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" data-text="<?php the_title() ?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-count="vertical" data-via="twitter-username-here"><span class="vhidden">Share on Twitter</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="socialite googleplus-one" href="https://plus.google.com/share" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" data-size="tall" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><span class="vhidden">Share on Google+</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="socialite facebook-like" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="60" data-show-faces="false"><span class="vhidden">Share on Facebook</span></a></li>
</ul>
';

    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'social_after_the_content' );
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{

$(‘.social-buttons’).one(‘mouseenter’, function()
{
Socialite.load($(this)[0]);
});

});
```

**CSS**

```
.social-buttons { display: block; list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 20px; }
.social-buttons > li { display: block; margin: 0; padding: 10px; float: left; }
.social-buttons .socialite { display: block; position: relative; background: url('http://tuts-authors.s3.amazonaws.com/wp.tutsplus.com/AhmadAwais/2012/08/29/social-sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat; }
.social-buttons .socialite-loaded { background: none !important; }

.social-buttons .twitter-share { width: 55px; height: 65px; background-position: 0 0; }
.social-buttons .googleplus-one { width: 50px; height: 65px; background-position: -75px 0; }
.social-buttons .facebook-like { width: 50px; height: 65px; background-position: -145px 0; }
.social-buttons .linkedin-share { width: 60px; height: 65px; background-position: -215px 0; }

.vhidden { border: 0; clip: rect(0 0 0 0); height: 1px; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; width: 1px; }
```

the js is in the js folder (theme/js) along with Socialite.min.js and the css file is also in its own folder (theme/css).

Comment: First: Please, really read through the FAQ. It will makes things a lot easier for everyone - you included. And no, I'm not only talking about this question. When you've read the FAQ and understand the sites mechanisms, then you'll see that it's ok to post updates in your question (and not in comments) or add solutions as answers to your own question and several other things how you can improve the overall stats for the site and get better answers to your own questions.

Comment: Ok, understand the edit thing...I changed my previous posts and added all my "edits" to the original post.

Comment: On two questions you still got comments on answers that are open. Sorry to push you that much, but we're already trying hard to solve as much open questions as possible, fix tags, misspellings, etc. and without everybody doing his part, it's - to be honest - a tough mission.

Comment: That is fair enough, I can appreciate how difficult this would be. I tried to edit all my posts with answers in the original posts.

Comment: Please edit the question and add your full code, so we can inspect it. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the post with the code I used

Comment: Notes: 1) It can be that the CDN simply denies hotlinking - save the sprite on your own server. 2) You're using `‘` instead of `'` in your JS 3) Make sure (developer tools for Google Chrome, FireBug for FireFox) that your stylesheets really load. 4) **ALWAYS** type code from tutorials into your editor. Never copy paste. This brings you into hells kitchen (see `'` in your JS).

Comment: I've have just copy&pasted from tutorials all this time :/ I will keep that in mind, also, thanks for pointing out the mistake in my JS. Changed that, still the same. So I downloaded Firebug (Awesome btw) and was looking through...(Edit) and i can see  `<script src=”/js/socialite.js” type=”text/javascript”>` but no mention of wptuts-social.js or wptuts-social.css (or wouldnt they show up...im not sure). Will continue to try  get things going in the meantime. Cheers Kaiser

Comment: You're welcome :) Btw: You added some copypasta in the comment again - look at your quotes. Ya really need to fix this ;)

Comment: I cant edit that post (too long), will I just delete it? That code is from firebug/html. I re-did the tutorial using the basic WP theme, exact same issue. So annoying...driving me crazy as I must be making a mistake somewhere. Thanks for all your help, I will let you know if i sort it.

Comment: I was getting desperate and copied the css into my main css file, the sprite now appears and the buttons are in place/clickable. But, the buttons have little counters above them which shows the user an amount. They only have "share on twitter" "share on google" etc, so something isnt right. I tried Firebug again, and I can see the main socalite.js, but no mention of two files from the tutorail (which are mentioned in the code and are in the right place on the theme install folder). Long shot, but any ideas?

Comment: FINALLY! Got it working :) For anybody else reading this, I created the files originally in sublime, but while in work i re-did everything...but in notepad. Works. Thanks for your help Kaiser, I appreciate you taking time to help me with this.

Comment: Please add your solution as answer. You can mark it as solution days later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kaiser pointed me to firebug (FF addon) which confirmed what I thought, the css/js files were not being loaded correctly. But everthing seemed ok. I copied the css into my main styles sheet and things started to look better (however, some things still didnt work).

I re-did the tutorial (for the fourth time), but this time I didn't use sublime (used notepad) and everything works. I can now remove the css from my main styles sheet and everything still works.

Thanks for the advice and the heads up on firebug...and when copying from tutorials :)